# Why would running Java in Dos window try and run an application wrapped in exe

Tags: java, windows, launch4j, izpack

Totally stumped this perhaps obvious to somebody. I package my Java application in an installer (using Izpack), once installed they run SongKong64.exe which is a wrapper around the java files created using Launch

This was not working for a customer he should be getting something like this:

```
debuglogfile is:C:\Users\Terrence\AppData\Roaming\SongKong\Logs/songkong_debug%u-%g.log
userlogfile is:C:\Users\Terrence\AppData\Roaming\SongKong\Logs/songkong_user%u-%g.log
17/02/2017 11.31.25:GMT:com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong:writeSystemInfo:SEVERE: SongKong 4.6 1070 15/02/2017 using Java 1.8.0_74 25.74-b02 64bit on Windows 10 10.0 amd64 initialized successfully
17/02/2017 11.31.25:GMT:com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong:writeSystemInfo:SEVERE: SongKong has been configured with minimum heap memory of 150 mb, maximum heap memory of 356 mb and maximum permanent memory of -32 mb
17/02/2017 11.31.26:GMT:com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong:writeSystemInfo:SEVERE: Username:Terrence:Domain:iPad-Laptop:RunningAsAdmin:false
17/02/2017 11.31.26:GMT:com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong:checkDatabase:SEVERE: Setting Db Folder:C:\Users\Terrence\AppData\Roaming\SongKong/Database
17/02/2017 11.31.26:GMT:com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil:createFactory:SEVERE: ----Initilizing Hibernate Session factory
17/02/2017 11.31.29:GMT:com.jthink.songkong.cmdline.SongKong:checkDatabase:SEVERE: Accessed Database okay
17/02/2017 11.31.32:GMT:com.jthink.acoustid.query.AbstractAcoustidQuery:performBasicSubmissionQuery:SEVERE: Posting to url:http://api.acoustid.org/v2//user/create_anonymous?format=xml&client=8XaBELgH
17/02/2017 11.32.47:GMT:com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil:closeFactory:SEVERE: ----Closing Hibernate Session factory

C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong>JVM64\bin\java -cp lib;lang  -Xms150m -Xmx400m  -jar lib/SongKong-4.6.jar
```

but instead getting

```
C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong>songkong64.exe

C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong>Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -m "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dsf
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: DSF:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -d "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dsf
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:48 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: DSF:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -r "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.dsf
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.dsf\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: DSF:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -m "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3 /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.mp3
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: MP3:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -d "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3 /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.mp3
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: MP3:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -r "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3 /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.mp3
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.mp3\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: MP3:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -m "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:49 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ogg
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.Match
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: OGG:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -d "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ogg
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.DeleteDuplicates
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: OGG:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -r "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.ogg
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ    (value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\(value not set)
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeHKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: targetKeyNodeExistsHKCU\Software\Classes\.ogg\shell\SongKong.UndoChanges
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu addContextMenu
SEVERE: OGG:AddContextMenu:false
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\lib\SongKong64.exe" -g -m "%1"
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Looking For key
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\.flac /ve
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.flac
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager inferTargetKeyNode
SEVERE: Checking Output:    (Default)    REG_SZ
Feb 14, 2017 7:38:50 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager executeCommand
SEVERE: Cmd:REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Classes\
```

So I asked him to bypass the exe and just run the pure java classes as follows. **But as you can see the output refers to songkong64.exe somehow, it doesnt make any sense how this can happen ?**

```
C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong>JVM64\bin\java -cp lib;lang  -Xms150m -Xmx400m  -jar lib/SongKong-4.6.jar
Feb 17, 2017 3:33:00 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 17, 2017 3:33:00 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 17, 2017 3:33:00 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 17, 2017 3:33:00 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.AddContextMenu buildLaunchCommand
SEVERE: Architecture is:amd64
Feb 17, 2017 3:33:00 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\SongKong64.exe" -g -m "%1"
```

....

If the customer installs on another computer it works fine.

Comment: It's hard to tell...  While you've given an expected and a failed log, there is no code to diagnose here.  What is SongKong doing and how is it building up the "launchCmd"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the output in your question, I guess the following lines:

```
Feb 17, 2017 3:33:00 PM com.jthink.songkong.Windows.ContextMenuManager createContextMenu
SEVERE: launchCmd:"C:\Program Files\Jthink\SongKong\SongKong64.exe" -g -m "%1"
```

..are trying to add an entry to the windows explorer context menu, to open files directly with `SongKong64.exe`? So probabily in the `ContextMenuManager.createContextMenu()` method the path to the `SongKong64.exe` is guessed based on the path of the jar? If you show some code of this method, maybe I can help you better.

Another possibility is that the problem comes from missing privileges, as it works for your customer if he installs it on another machine.

Comment: you are quite right, I had it in my head that this output was from something in the exe wrapper provided by launch4j but of course it is my code for adding entries to the Windows context menu, I had forgotten all about that !!!. What I cant tell if the problem is with this code or if goes wrong AFTER running this code, will add some debugging and get usert to retry.

Comment: Awarded you bounty as your answer has at least explained the output and shoud lead me to get a fix.